How to apply concrete dropout during inference time with batch size > 1 in Keras
I am trying to implement the concrete dropout method for a regression task, as described in Gal et al. (2017) (the paper). I am implementing it in R with the new Keras3 R package and a tensorflow backend. My implementation is based on the code for Python and the older version 2 of Keras for R in:

https://github.com/yaringal/ConcreteDropout
https://github.com/aurelio-amerio/ConcreteDropout
https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2018-11-12-uncertainty_estimates_dropout

Though it seems to work with batch_size = 1, I have a strange behavior with batch_size > 1 (during training). When predicting posterior samples with dropout, the slope is weaker and the regression is completely out of the data points.
We can see that dropout is effectively applied during inference (stochasticity in predictions). I suspect a problem with the re-scaling of weights for dropout during inference time (in predict()) but I can't make it work properly. In this blog you can see that it actually works with batch_size > 1 in keras version 2.
UPDATE: It probably has something to do with input_size not being properly managed during training. I tried different combinations of batch size at training and inference time. Changing batch size at inference had no effect. Changing batch size during training was the cause of this issue. At batch size = 2 I already saw a weaker slope. The higher is batch size, the weaker is the slope until a slope of zero is achieved. There is a weird division somewhere.
UPDATE 2: in fact, when batch size increases, it always predict the mean of the dataset (mean of y), for every x value. As an intuition, it is as if the algorithm is learning to predict the mean of the batch, instead of learning the 'slope' of the regression.
See the figures below for batch_size = 1 and batch_size = 32. Blue points are test data (true y) and dark points are mean predictions (y_pred) with epistemic uncertainty (grey ribbon).
Batch size = 1
Batch size = 32
Do you have some ideas of where I could be wrong in the following code?
The implementation of the concrete dropout layer :
layer_concrete_dropout <- new_layer_class(
  classname = "concrete_dropout",
  
  public = list(
    weight_regularizer = 1e-6,
    dropout_regularizer = 1e-5,
    init_min = 0.1,
    init_max = 0.1,
    is_mc_dropout = TRUE,
    trainable = TRUE,
    
    initialize = function(wrapped_layer,
                          weight_regularizer = 1e-6,
                          dropout_regularizer = 1e-5,
                          init_min = 0.1,
                          init_max = 0.1,
                          is_mc_dropout = TRUE,
                          trainable = TRUE,
                          seed = NULL,
                          ...) {
      super$initialize(...)
      self$wrapped_layer = wrapped_layer
      self$weight_regularizer <- weight_regularizer
      self$dropout_regularizer <- dropout_regularizer
      self$is_mc_dropout <- is_mc_dropout
      self$trainable = trainable
      self$init_min <- op_log(init_min) - op_log(1 - init_min)
      self$init_max <- op_log(init_max) - op_log(1 - init_max)
      self$seed_gen = random_seed_generator(seed = seed)
    },
    
    build = function(input_shape) {
      self$wrapped_layer$build(input_shape)

      self$p_logit <- self$add_weight(
        name = "p_logit",
        shape = shape(1),
        initializer = initializer_random_uniform(self$init_min, self$init_max),
        trainable = TRUE
      )
    },
    
    compute_output_shape = function(input_shape) {
      self$wrapped_layer$compute_output_shape(input_shape)
    },
    
    concrete_dropout = function(x) {
      eps <- op_cast(1e-7, tf$float32)
      temp <- 0.1
      
      unif_noise = random_uniform(shape = x$shape[-1], seed = self$seed_gen)

      drop_prob <- op_log(self$p + eps) - 
        op_log(1 - self$p + eps) + 
        op_log(unif_noise + eps) - 
        op_log(1 - unif_noise + eps)
      drop_prob <- op_sigmoid(drop_prob / temp)
      
      random_tensor <- 1 - drop_prob
      
      retain_prob <- 1 - self$p
      x <- x * random_tensor
      x <- x / retain_prob
      
      return(x)
    },
    
    
    call = function(inputs, training = NULL) {
      input_shape = inputs$shape[[2]]

      # The dropout rate
      self$p = op_sigmoid(self$p_logit)

      # initialise regularizer / prior KL term
      # Compute the weight regularizer
      weight = self$wrapped_layer$kernel
      kernel_regularizer = self$weight_regularizer * op_sum(op_square(weight)) / (1 - self$p)
      # Compute the dropout regularizer
      dropout_regularizer = self$p * op_log(self$p)
      dropout_regularizer = dropout_regularizer + (1 - self$p) * op_log(1 - self$p)
      dropout_regularizer = dropout_regularizer * self$dropout_regularizer * input_dim
      # Total regularization loss
      regularizer = op_sum(kernel_regularizer + dropout_regularizer)
      
      self$wrapped_layer$add_loss(regularizer)
      
      self$wrapped_layer(self$concrete_dropout(inputs))
    }
  )
)

The model
input <- layer_input(shape = input_dim)

output <- input %>% layer_concrete_dropout(
  layer_dense(units = num_hidden_dim, activation = "relu"),
  weight_regularizer = wd,
  dropout_regularizer = dd
) %>% layer_concrete_dropout(
  layer_dense(units = num_hidden_dim, activation = "relu"),
  weight_regularizer = wd,
  dropout_regularizer = dd
) %>% layer_concrete_dropout(
  layer_dense(units = num_hidden_dim, activation = "relu"),
  weight_regularizer = wd,
  dropout_regularizer = dd
)

mean <- output %>% layer_concrete_dropout(
  layer_dense(units = output_dim),
  weight_regularizer = wd,
  dropout_regularizer = dd
)

log_var <- output %>% layer_concrete_dropout(
  layer_dense(units = output_dim),
  weight_regularizer = wd,
  dropout_regularizer = dd
)

output <- layer_concatenate(list(mean, log_var))

model = keras_model(input, output)

heteroscedastic_loss <- function(y_true, y_pred) {
  mean <- y_pred[, 1:output_dim]
  log_var <- y_pred[, (output_dim + 1):(output_dim * 2)]
  precision <- op_exp(-log_var)
  op_sum(precision * (y_true - mean) ^ 2 + log_var, axis = 2)
}

The data, a linear model with random noise
gen_data_1d <- function(n) {
  sigma <- 1
  X <- matrix(rnorm(n))
  w <- 2
  b <- 8
  Y <- matrix(X %*% w + b + sigma * rnorm(n))
  list(X, Y)
}

c(X, Y) %<-% gen_data_1d(n_train + n_val)

c(X_train, Y_train) %<-% list(X[1:n_train], Y[1:n_train])
c(X_val, Y_val) %<-% list(X[(n_train + 1):(n_train + n_val)], 
                          Y[(n_train + 1):(n_train + n_val)])

Training the model
model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_adam(learning_rate=0.001),
  loss = heteroscedastic_loss,
  metrics = c(custom_metric("heteroscedastic_loss", heteroscedastic_loss))
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  X_train,
  Y_train,
  epochs = 60,
  batch_size = 1,
)

Predicting the posterior samples and uncertainty
num_MC_samples <- 20

MC_samples <- array(0, dim = c(num_MC_samples, n_val, 2 * output_dim))
for (k in 1:num_MC_samples) {
  MC_samples[k, , ] = (model %>% predict(X_val))
}

# the means are in the first output column
means <- MC_samples[, , 1:output_dim]  
# average over the MC samples
predictive_mean <- apply(means, 2, mean) 

epistemic_uncertainty <- apply(means, 2, var) 

logvar <- MC_samples[, , (output_dim + 1):(output_dim * 2)]
aleatoric_uncertainty <- exp(colMeans(logvar))

df <- data.frame(
  x = X_val,
  y = Y_val,
  y_pred = predictive_mean,
  e_u_lower = predictive_mean - sqrt(epistemic_uncertainty),
  e_u_upper = predictive_mean + sqrt(epistemic_uncertainty),
  a_u_lower = predictive_mean - sqrt(aleatoric_uncertainty),
  a_u_upper = predictive_mean + sqrt(aleatoric_uncertainty),
  u_overall_lower = predictive_mean - 
    sqrt(epistemic_uncertainty) - 
    sqrt(aleatoric_uncertainty),
  u_overall_upper = predictive_mean + 
    sqrt(epistemic_uncertainty) + 
    sqrt(aleatoric_uncertainty)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y_pred)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = e_u_lower, ymax = e_u_upper), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y), colour = "blue", alpha = 0.3) +
  theme_bw()

I tried to be as close to possible to the code of the three sources I gave earlier. This actual version of the code is a mix between the three references. None of the three versions worked with batch size > 1. I tried to force training = TRUE in layers.
I tried using predict_on_batch instead of predict().
I tried putting the computation of the weight regularizer within build() or within call().
